# Radio button list not binding properlly

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I'm having radio button list under repeater.
On Repeaters item data bound I'm binding radio button list but it is binding for every character in datareader.
If I change control to radio button it works fine.

```
<cms:CMSRepeater ID="rpt_Questions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_Questions_ItemDataBound">              

              <ItemTemplate>
                  <div><span class="presenter"><%# Container.DataItem%></span></div>
                      <div>
                       <%--   <Strong><%# Container.DataItem%></Strong>--%>
                              <ul class="clearfix">
                                    <cms:QueryRepeater ID="rpt_Answers" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_Answers_ItemDataBound">
                                        <ItemTemplate>                                               
                                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtAnswers" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </cms:QueryRepeater>
                              </ul>
                    </div>               
             </ItemTemplate>
        </cms:CMSRepeater>

protected void rpt_Answers_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        RadioButtonList rblAnswers = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rbtAnswers");


        System.Data.DataRowView drAnswer;
        drAnswer = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        rblAnswers.DataSource = drAnswer["Answer"].ToString();
        rblAnswers.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Suppose I am expecting 3 radio button with with values `a1,a2,a3`
It is creating 6 radio button with
`a ,1,a,2,a3`

Is this because  I am having repeater and then repater and then checkbox list?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void rpt_Answers_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        RadioButtonList rblAnswers = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rbtAnswers");


        System.Data.DataRowView drAnswer;
        drAnswer = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        rblAnswers.DataSource = drAnswer["Answer"];
        rblAnswers.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi

Finally issue is been solved  
I created my structure as   
One repeater and inside that  I create radio button list 
On load I bound my repeater and on its ItemDataBound I bind my radio button list

Answer (score 0):

Sudhir's answer might help your case. You might try to check the type of the item first, and add a value if it's the item you looking for.

But from what you provided as a result, I am suspicious that you are actually sending 6 values to the reader. You see, if it creates 6 buttons "1,a,2,a,3,a" it means it gets 6 values.

If that's the case, you should create a list which has "1 a" value together, and send it to the repeater which has the proper areas to show.

Comment: All values going to be bound on radio button list are coming from database ,and untill those get bound to radio button list it looks fine in my data, but one it is getting bound it it bounded by char to char

Comment: Yea, but how many rows your data object has? Is it equal with the exact number of the answers, or double of them?

Comment: I am having 1 question and 3 to 4 answers of those
for those answers i want to create radiobutton lst

Comment: Would you check how many rows are coming inside the data object on debug mode? You can also check how many times your DataBound event is fired as well.

Comment: Correct data is coming and loop is also executing correctlly is it something cz of repeater then repated and then checkboxlist  ?

Comment: Hi

Finally issue is been solved  
I created my structure as   
One repeater and inside that  I create radio button list 
On load I bound my repeater and on its ItemDataBound I bind my radio button list